# Error al guardar campos de un formulario

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tengo un formulario hecho en MVC ASP.NET, usando Entity framework para persistencia. Intento grabar los datos, pero al hacer click en guardar, Visual Studio me tira una excepción en la línea `ctx.Empleado.Add(em);` del action Crear.
Luego al hacer click en continuar me dice "Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)". qu está pasando?

Controlador:

```
using Ejercicio06.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ejercicio06.Controllers
{
    public class EmpleadoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Empleado/Index
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Empleado/Crear
        public ActionResult Crear()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Crear(FormCollection form)
        {
            Context ctx = new Context();
            Empleado em = new Empleado();

            em.nombre= form["nombre"];
            em.apellido = form["apellido"];
            ctx.Empleado.Add(em);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Modelo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Ejercicio06.Models
{
    public class Empleado
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Vista:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Crear</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2 class="text-center">Registrarse</h2><br>

            <form action="Crear" method="POST">
                <!-- INPUT NOMBRE -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar Mail" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <!-- INPUT APELLIDO -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresar Apellido" />
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- BOTON GUARDAR -->
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>

                    <!-- LINK SALIR -->
                    <a href="../" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

verifica primero tu string connection en Web.conf

```
<add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBname.mdf;Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

siempre recuerda que el nombre de la cadena lo tienes que definir en tu contexto ya que usas entity framework

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{

    public AppContext() : base("DBContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Empleado> Empleado { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

si eres nuevo en asp.net mvc y quieres ver cómo funcionan los formularios esta bien pero si no te recomiendo que uses los scaffolds de asp. mvc que te harán la vida más fásil. te explico en un ejemplo.

Creas un proyecto y agregas en tu carpeta models tu clase empleado

```
 public class Empleado
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

Compilas la aplicación o le das rebuild. Luego en tu carpeta controller das clic derecho add controller y seleccionas la opción MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework. En controller name "EmpleadoController", en model class seleccionas tu clase de modelo, en este caso empleado. Y como no tienes un contexto todavía definido en la casilla Data context class das clic en el botón "new data context" y se te va a generar un contexto automático, le cambias el nombre si quieres pero siempre deja el apellido Context. de esta manera ya has echo un CRUD con Entity Framework de manera muy simple. Corre tu navegador y verás

Comment: En context.cs tengo eso:
     public partial class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
            : base("name=Context")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Empleado> Empleado { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Empleado>()
                .Property(e => e.nombre)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Empleado>()
                .Property(e => e.apellido)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }

Comment: en mi web.config mo tengo eso que pusiste. no se supone que lo debe crear el framework?

Comment: te puse una guia ahora muy simple si sigues bien todos los pasos que te puse todo te irá bien. Sólo te pido que explotes al máximo todos los beneficios de Asp MVC y Visual Studio.

Comment: em funciona pero no me graba nada en la BD. Si creo primer el data model me tira una excepcion.

Comment: deberia funcionarte todo bien. despues de crear el modelo Empleado le diste Rebuild a tu app ?

Comment: Si puedes crea un proyecto nuevo desde 0 y utiliza la via que te explico paso a paso.

Comment: es lo que hice pero  me dice: error al ejecutar el generador de códigos selecccionado

Comment: El error te lo da tratando de insertar un controlador con vistas usando EF?

Comment: si, solo tengo el modelo

Comment: Si sólo tienes el modelo, entonces en tu solution explorer buscar la raiz osea el nombre de tu app, le das clic derecho y Rebuild. Tambien quería preguntarte si estas trabajando con el SQL server express que trae vs pues mi ejemplo es con ese. Si estas trabajndo con un servidor SQL en producción la cadena de conección es otra distinta por completa

Comment: le hice rebuild, no se que pasa, Uso SQL Express 2012

Comment: Después de hacer el rebuild procede con agregar un controlador de la forma que te expliqué

Comment: hice todo lo que me dijiste